# How is use property of struct underneath of enum enum in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to create a struct of Circle to represent a circle and enum with different fraction to return the coordinates of circle. My question is how I can use radius variable with the coord so I can calculate the position for oneEighths, quarter and half

```
public struct Circle {

    public var radius: Float

    public init(radius: Float) {
        self.radius = radius
    }

    public enum Fraction {
        case oneEighths
        case quarter
        case half

        public var coord: (Float, Float) {
            switch self {
            /// how to use radius property to replace 150?
            case .oneEighths: (radius /1.414, radius/1.414) /// if self.radius equals 150, it should return (150/1.414, 150/1.414)
            case .quarter: (radius, 0) /// if self.radius equals 150
            case .half: (0, radius) /// if self.radius equals 150
            }
        }
    }
}
```

error: instance member `radius` of type `Circle` cannot be used on instance of nested type `Circle.Fraction`

Comment: Nested enums are encapsulated. Make the `var` a `func` and pass `radius` in a parameter.

Comment: Or, if put a bit more precisely, nested types in Swift are always static (unlike, for example, Java, where you can define both dynamic and static nested types.) It means that it doesn't matter if you define the type nested inside another one, it doesn't have any association with instances of the enclosing type. Think of the nested and enclosing types as two separate types, instances of which are instantiated separately and interact with each other as two unrelated objects. "Nestedness" in Swift is only for grouping and name spaces, nothing more.

Comment: Why not make the cases into computed properties on Circle instead?

Answer (score 0):

i am little bit confused in this question. but here i think you can use `associated enum` like below example.

```
public struct Circle {
    public enum Fraction {
        case oneEighths(radius:Float)
        case quarter(radius:Float)
        case half(radius:Float)

        public var coord: (Float, Float) {
            switch self {
            case .oneEighths(let radius):
                return (radius / 1.414, radius / 1.414)
            case .quarter(let radius):
                return (radius, 0)
            case .half(let radius):
                return (0, radius)
            }
        }
    }
}

let circle = Circle.Fraction.oneEighths(radius: 150)
print(circle.coord) //"(106.08203, 106.08203)\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrapped enum `Fraction` is just a type that is defined nested inside the `Circle` struct. The `radius` isn't relevant here because its scope comes from a different data structure. You can either change `coord` to a function that takes `radius` as a parameter or re-define the enum cases with an associated type:

```swift
case oneEighths(radius: Float)
case quarter(radius: Float)
case half(radius: Float)

public var coord: (Float, Float) {
   switch self {
    case .oneEighths(let radius):
        return (radius/1.414, radius/1.414)
    case .quarter(let radius):
        return (radius, 0)
    case .half(let radius):
        return (0, radius)
    }
}
```

Or

```swift
public func coord(with radius: Float) -> (Float, Float) {
    switch self {
    case .oneEighths: 
        return (radius/1.414, radius/1.414)
    case .quarter:
        return (radius, 0)
    case .half:
        return (0, radius)
    }
}
```